# How to fix "VBA just run a part of code and ignore another"

Tags: excel, vba

When I press F8 to step through the code line by line, it works perfect. However when I use F5 to run the the whole sub, VBA just runs one `For-Next` Loop. I am wondering if anyone is having the same issue?

```
Sub InputPurchaseData()

Dim rngPurchaseInfoLoop As Range, rngPurchaseInfo As Range
Dim rngPurchaseItemsFieldLoop As Range, rngPurchaseItemsField As Range
Dim rngPurchaseItemsLoop As Range, rngPurchaseItems As Range
Dim rngPurchaseDataFieldLoop As Range, rngPurchaseDataField As Range
Dim rngPurchaseDataRowLoop As Range, rngPurchaseDataRow As Range
Dim lngPurchaseItemRow As Long, lngPurchaseDataRow As Long
Dim msgOption As Boolean
Dim strPurchaseNumber As String

wsPurchaseOrder.Activate

Set rngPurchaseInfo = wsPurchaseOrder.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Set rngPurchaseItemsField = wsPurchaseOrder.Range("B1", Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)).Find(What:="ITEM", _
        MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Set rngPurchaseItems = Range(rngPurchaseItemsField.Offset(2, 0), Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0))

Set rngPurchaseItemsField = Range(rngPurchaseItemsField, rngPurchaseItemsField.End(xlToRight))

Set rngPurchaseDataField = wsPurchaseData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(1)

Set rngPurchaseDataRow = wsPurchaseData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 1)
For Each rngPurchaseItemsLoop In rngPurchaseItems
    If IsNumeric(rngPurchaseItemsLoop.Value) Then
        lngPurchaseItemRow = rngPurchaseItemsLoop.Row - rngPurchaseItems.Resize(1).Row + 2

    For Each rngPurchaseInfoLoop In rngPurchaseInfo

        Set rngPurchaseDataFieldLoop = rngPurchaseDataField.Find(What:=rngPurchaseInfoLoop.Value, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not rngPurchaseDataFieldLoop Is Nothing Then _
            rngPurchaseDataFieldLoop.Offset(rngPurchaseDataRow.Rows.Count).Value = rngPurchaseInfoLoop.Offset(, 1).Value

    Next rngPurchaseInfoLoop
    For Each rngPurchaseItemsFieldLoop In rngPurchaseItemsField

        Set rngPurchaseDataFieldLoop = rngPurchaseDataField.Find(What:=rngPurchaseItemsFieldLoop.Value, MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not rngPurchaseDataFieldLoop Is Nothing Then _
            rngPurchaseDataFieldLoop.Offset(rngPurchaseDataRow.Rows.Count).Value = rngPurchaseItemsFieldLoop.Offset(lngPurchaseItemRow).Value

    Next rngPurchaseItemsFieldLoop

    End If

Next rngPurchaseItemsLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: Pardon the candor, but to circumvent my having to check each variable is accoutned for, does your module lead with "OPTION EXPLICIT"?  If not, that might be a first start.  The thing to check after that is that everything is qualified (cells have sheet references, etc.).

Comment: You do not need to set ranges for everything like this. And if you MUST, you should use short hand variables. Most of your variable names are longer than just typing out the range they are meant to represent `ws.Range("A1")` which kind of defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: Can you explain what you would like your code to do on a macro level/

Comment: @Cyril Yes, my module lead with "Option Explicit". The code works fine when Im stepping line by line using F8. But that not for F5

Comment: @urdearboy I've got to sort out sheets of data for analysis step

Comment: First of all: why do you not full qualify e.g. rngPurchaseItems and next variables? "Set rngPurchaseItems = Range()" no worksheet is here definied and in rngPurchaseItemsField. Where are you setting rngPurchaseItemsLoop variable? The second one: after set and fully qualifing variables if it will still fail you can also add breakpoint after main For Each loop and check how many items are in rngPurchaseItems an how many numeric values (so the macro will run in 2 steps, from start to your checkpoint, and the rest of your code if everything is OK with your watches).